# How to add a class to element if another element is empty?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to remove the existing class (blue) and add a new class (red) to the <'h2'> when the <'a'> is empty.

```
<div id="heading" class="header">
   <h2 id="title" class="blue">Header text goes here</h2>
   <a class="info" href="#"></a>
</div>

<style>
  .blue{color:blue}
  .red{color:red}
</style>
```

I have tried a few variations but without success. This is my latest.

```
$("#heading a.info:empty").removeClass('blue').addClass("red");
```

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `.text()` to find if it is empty

```
var a =$(".info").text().trim();
a===""?($("#title").removeClass("blue").addClass('red')):''
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/66kLepxx/)

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly for me and was quite easy to adjust.

Answer (score 3):

```js
if($("#heading a.info").text() === ''){
  $("#heading h2").removeClass('blue').addClass("red");
}
```

```css
.blue{color:blue}
 .red{color:red}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="heading" class="header">
   <h2 id="title" class="blue">Header text goes here</h2>
   <a class="info" href="#"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
if ($("#heading a.info:empty")) {
  $("#title").removeClass('blue').addClass("red");
}
```

```css
.blue {
  color: blue
}
.red {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="heading" class="header">
  <h2 id="title" class="blue">Header text goes here</h2>
  <a class="info" href="#"></a>
</div>
```

Should remove from `h2` not from anchor

Answer (score 0):

`:empty` returns a collection of elements. And you need to add/remove class from `h2`,

so use **[`.prev()`](https://api.jquery.com/prev/)** to get the previous sibling.

```
$("#heading a.info:empty")
                 .prev('#title')
                 .removeClass('blue')
                 .addClass("red");
```